# Oracle query: Parent/Child

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables. (table1 & table2)

**Table1 Parent:**

```
ID        | Description
11058744  | A
11058745  | A
11058746  | A
```

**Table2 Child:**

```
ID        | REFCODE            
11058745  | 11058744
11058744  | 11058745
11058746  | 11058744
11058744  | 11058746
```

I want the **result** looks like below:

```
ID        | REFCODE 
11058744  | 11058744 
11058745  | 11058744   
11058746  | 11058744
```

Comment: What is the logic to get result? Does not look so clear

Comment: can you provide a better explanation for what you actually want / what this means?

Comment: for 11058746 what's the reflexion ? is it :

11058746 -> 11058744 -> 11058745 -> 11058744

Answer (score 0):

The following query will produce the results you requested:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT DISTINCT ID AS ID FROM TABLE1),
     B AS (SELECT MIN(REFCODE) AS REFCODE FROM TABLE2)
SELECT A.ID, B.REFCODE
  FROM A
  CROSS JOIN B;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1ab11/7).

Share and enjoy.